# How can I print via a WiFi printer in Android using a Wi-Fi Direct connection?

Tags: android, printing, wifi

My main question: Suppose you are in the street carrying an Android tablet and a WiFi printer. Is it possible to connect to that WiFi printer by Android device and print directly without any LAN network joined to?

I mean **is it possible to connect to a WiFi printer like a Bluetooth printer**?

Comment: Samsung does it, so surely it is possible.

Comment: @blackbelt How? can you explain more or suggest a reference?

Comment: I used a software from samsung with its wifi printer. That's all I know

Comment: thanks, But I need an Android programming solution

Comment: I was answering to your question "is it possible to connect to a WiFi printer like a Bluetooth printer". I am sorry I am not able to help further

Comment: So I guess also, that the printer brand will not matter - right, or it will be a HP printer ?

Comment: Printing to an arbitrary networked printer is hard, since you need to have the PPDs for that printer. There are a couple of apps on the Play Store that do that. 

Doing it over Wi-Fi direct requires Wi-Fi direct support for the printer (not sure if the new ones support it). After that you're back to printing to a normal networked printer.

Answer (score 2):

Well to answer your question, let me explain you how this works. 
To print a file via bluetooth you need have corresponding profiles in the phone like

- BPP - Basic Printing Profile
- HCRP - Hardcopy Replacement Profile
- BIP - Basic Imaging Profile etc.

If the phones have this profiles built into the bluetooth stack, then you can develop a top layer application using bluetooth api's and use these features.

For Wifi priting, there are lot of cloud print apps in Google play store which you could use. 
To achieve wifi printing, you can setup a server and do a cloud push to the server and server pushes the file to the printer. There are lot of material available online to do this.,